# how to handle overlap with Super User?

Tags: discussion

How should we handle overlap with [Super User](http://www.superuser.com)? There are only [four gis tagged questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gis) right now, so we could just ask to have them moved over, but is that appropriate?

Comment: Super User doesn't seem to be in our realm, however Stack Overflow would be.  It would be nice to see stackoverflow's question migrate over to our site so that we get the traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be a couple months before we'll be able to transfer questions.  I personally wouldn't worry too much about past questions, and I think if our community picks up steam Super User folks will naturally start referring people here.

Comment: +1, I agree, I wouldn't use superuser for GIS questions anyway.